# Summing multiple ranges as a conditional statement in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements

I am trying to avoid using VBA if that's at all possible and I most certainly think that it is!

I'm currently trying to sum up a range if a certain condition is met. My function works when the range is limited and small, but does not work when I encompass my actual desired range. Here is some snippets of code:

```
=SUMIF(B13:M13,P23, B15:M15)
```

That function currently sums from B15 to M15 if there are any matches in between B13 and M13 with P23. It works like a charm. If there are discrepancies in between B13 and M13 it will only sum that matches which is exactly what I want it to do.

I want it to cover a much broader range, so I altered my formula as follows:

```
=SUMIF(B13:M13:B32:M32:B51:M51,P23, B15:M15:B34:M34:B53:M53)
```

I want it to do the same thing as before. I want it to analyze B13:M13 as well as B32:M32 as well as B51:M51 and compare it to P23. If there are matches I want it to sum B15:M15 as well as B34:M34 as well as B53:M53. If there are non matches, I want them to be omitted as was the case in my previous function.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my formula?

Comment: Would it be possible to show the data and expected outcome?

Comment: Certainly. The data in P23 is a mold number, for instance "21222". The data in the ranges B13:M13 B32:M32 and B51:M51 also contain mold numbers. So if the mold number currently running in the aforementioned ranges matches the mold in P23 then it should sum  the data in B15:M15 B34:M34 and B53:M53 which are production numbers that pertain to the the machine in question. For this example the formula is in cell U23 which should act as an inventory count that summed up the corresponding cells. Let me know if that helps! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sumproduct is you friend here. Take a look at @simoco answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your formula `=SUMIF(B13:M13:B32:M32:B51:M51,P23, B15:M15:B34:M34:B53:M53)` converts to `=SUMIF(B13:M51,P23, B15:M53)` (you can check it for example using "Evaluate formula" tool in the "Formulas" Ribbon or by entering in cell `B18` value, euqals to `P23`, and another value in `B20` - your formula will add value from `B20` to the result). And it doesen't calculate propertly, because you have some text values in `B16:M33, B35:M52`

So, you can use following formula instead:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B13:M13=P23)*(B15:M15)+(B32:M32=P23)*(B34:M34)+(B51:M51=P23)*(B53:M53))
```

---

**Here is result of evaluating your formula** (`=SUMIF(B13:M13:B32:M32:B51:M51,P23, B15:M15:B34:M34:B53:M53)`):

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Excel is throwing up a #VALUE! warning. It was doing the same thing for some of the other things that I tried. It says that "A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type". I ensured that there are no strings in any of the cells. They're all formatted as numbers. I even went as far as populating each cells so that blank cells wouldn't throw it off. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: simoco's solution should work even without making it array function